# Prompts for parameterized groups

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Got a report that gives the user a Group by parameter with two possible values - Customer and Country. If user selects Customers then the report groups on Customers else on Country if that is the user selection.
I want to create two parameters Customer and Country for filtering reports. 
I want to structure the report in a way that Customer parameter shows up only when Group by is Customers, similarly for Country - prompt only when group by is country. 
Both the parameters should not show up at the same time as that will confuse the user. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have optionally available parameters in Crystal, unless this is a new feature in XI onwards.

An alternative approach would be (in addition to your group by parameter) to create a second parameter with a relatively generic name - something like "group selection values" - and select customer values by this second parameter where Customers is the selected grouping option, otherwise select country values by this second parameter.